# Example of a continuous function $ f: X\rightarrow Y$ that is not closed in product of X and Y

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I need to show f is not a closed subset ( different than saying its not a closed function. And I have been thinking of examples of continuous but not closed subsets. if I defined a function f from R to R , the topology on the domain is standard topology and on the codomain is Cofinite topology( which isnt a hausdorff space) such that f(x)=3. its easy to prove why its continuous but to show why it isn't a closed subset of product of X and Y, I took a point (1,4) that doesn't belong to f but then i kind of got confused of what to do next. If I go on to prove that the complement of f isn't open. I don't know If I am on the right track  or even if my example is correct or not? any examples and simple explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: thats the point. I wanted my  topology on Y not to be Hausdorff actually. i forgot to mention a theorem I got the idea from which stated" if f is a continuous mapping from X space to Y hausdorff space then f is closed subset of product of X and Y". i tried to apply this theorem (instead of taking a hausdorff space , i defined cofinite topology). doesn't this theorem make it easier to find an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Your function actually is closed in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ when $\Bbb R$ has the cofinite topology. Use the identity function, $f(x)=x$, instead. Let $p=\langle x,y\rangle$, where $x,y\in\Bbb R$ and $x\ne y$. Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $p$; then there are open sets $V$ and $W$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $p\in V\times W\subseteq U$. Since $\Bbb R$ has the cofinite topology, there are finite sets $F,G\subseteq\Bbb R$ such that $V=\Bbb R\setminus F$ and $W=\Bbb R\setminus G$. Use this to show that $f\cap(V\times W)\ne\varnothing$; this will show that $p\in(\operatorname{cl}f)\setminus f$ and hence that $f$ is not closed.

If you need a further hint, there’s one in the spoiler-protected box:

> Find a point $y\in V\cap W$.

Comment: Note: the identity function $X\to X$ has closed graph iff $X$ is Hausdorff. In general, a space $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if for every continuous $f\colon X\to Y$, the graph of f is closed in $X\times Y$.

Comment: Sure, no problem